# Interface needed to transfer contents in a table on a web page to the Add New Product interface

Tags: plugins, table, user-interface

I will attempt to clarify this situation since the initial feedback was that it wasn't a question/or was vague.

I am having an e-commerce site built.  The developer is using a WP template purchased through Theme Forest written by Maya.  It is called Maya Shop.  We are also using the Woo Commerce plug in for the remaining e-commerce functions.  Either Woo Commerce or WP has a product input feature called "Add Product".  This interface is too complex for my intended users (who are artist-members).  My goal is to create a input sheet in table format on a web page and have the artists load their products into this sheet instead of the "Add Product" interface.  As this will be a loose affiliation of artists it won't be possible to train each one on the use of the standard WP interfaces.  I'm sure that creating a table on a web page with the appropriate drop down choices is not an issue.  What I'm being told is not possible is creating a table that will populate the Add Product interface.  I am also being told that if we create such a table, and allow it to load the product info directly into the WP MySQL DB it will not work, that the coding is too complex and will likely break something else.  What I'm asking is how does one create a simple input form on a web page that will successfully load the product information into either the database or the "Add Product" interface.  If this is too general or basic a question, please direct me to an answer as neither I nor my developer have found it.

Comment: Can you break it up a bit? Tad hard to read such a huge paragraph

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using an **extremely unique** configuration:

> It is called Maya Shop. We are also using the Woo Commerce plug in for
>   the remaining e-commerce functions.

Two e-commerce platforms?

Considering the uniqueness and the fact that you already have a developer on this project:

1. This question is very unlikely to apply to anyone else.
2. The developer knows more about the project then anyone here.

It's very unlikely that someone unfamiliar with your unique requirements could offer more insight than what your resource has already provided.

Can a custom interface be written? Certainly it can.

Are there risks and complexity? Absolutely, there is more to adding products (to either platform) than simply populating the database. Each has it's own unique process within the code.

Any custom interface would/could bypass that code and processing. Creating any number of problems and issues that would be extremely difficult to troubleshoot.